# css slector jquery: how to select first occurance of class after a particular class

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have the following html

```
<ul class="main"> ... </ul>
<div class="submain">...</div>  --> select this
<div class="submain">...</div>
<div class="submain">...</div>

...

<ul class="main"> ... </ul>
<div class="submain">...</div>  --> select this
<div class="submain">...</div>
<div class="submain">...</div>
```

How to select all the first submain elements after main.

Answer (score 2):

**You can do it like this**

For this case you need to select the sibling of the class so that can be achieved with `+` selector.

`The element+element selector is used to select elements that is placed immediately after (not inside) the first specified element.`
You can read up more here 
[Adjacent sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator)

```css
.main + .submain{
  color:green;
  background:'blue';
}
```

```html
<ul class="main"> ... </ul>
<div class="submain">Selected</div>  --> select this
<div class="submain">...</div>
<div class="submain">...</div>

...

<ul class="main"> ... </ul>
<div class="submain">Selected</div>  --> select this
<div class="submain">...</div>
<div class="submain">...</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As Code Maniac said - use "+" combinator to select adjacent siblings. From me, I'll give you link to the docs of how CSS combinators works:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors#Combinators